# Replacing entire vue.js container

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a vue.js widget that is instantiated as follows:

```
var foo = new Vue({
    el: '#v-container',
    methods: {
        populate:function() {
            // some custom code
        }
    },
});
```

The html is something along the following lines:

```
<div id="main-container">
  <lots of other HTML>
  <div id="v-container">
    <a href="#" v-on:click="populate">Foo</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This all works perfectly, and my data binding and custom methods work without any problems.

However, the `#v-container` element is contained inside of another element called `#main-container`. In some cases, the entire `#main-container` is replaced via a legacy jquery ajax method as follows:

`$('#main-container').replaceWith(result.content);`

Once this happens, then the vue.js widget stops responding to the `v-on click` event handler.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: You would need to reinstantiate your component after replacing the content.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that if you replace the entire container, then the component markup will be deleted. How you resolve this is dependent on your legacy code, if it injects a `div` with an `id` then you may be able to simply `append` it in the `created()` method of your Vue instance:

```
// Get "v-container" content
var vContainer = $("#v-container").html();

// An ajax call to replace everything!
$("#main-container").replaceWith('<div id="legacy-container">I\'ve replaced everything</div>');

new Vue({
  el: "#legacy-container",
  created() {
    $("#legacy-container").append('<div id="v-container">'+vContainer+'</div>');
  }
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ghL5u41/